# Can we use XBAP (WPF browser app) built using .net 3.5, on client machine having only .net 3.0

Tags: wpf, xbap

I have an XBAP application built using .net framework 3.5. It's published with full trust on a web server. I am able to use it on client machine having .net framework 3.5.

Question: can I also use this XBAP application on a client machine having only .net framework 3.0? That is no .net 3.5 on client machine.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

- .Net applications require the .Net runtime.
- You cannot run a .Net 3.5 application in machine that does not have the .Net 3.5 runtime installed.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering. But if it's a XBAP browser app then still we would need the .net framework 3.5 runtime? I thought XBAP browser would bring in .net 3.5 with it in the browsers cache. But it would need .net 3.0 atleast for Code Access Security.

Comment: @Piyush XBAP is just a "mask" to make users believe they're using a web application when they're not. It's still a WPF application, just doesn't have it's own window.